# VS2015 Project not loading - typescript version

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

Getting the following message when trying to load up a project in VS2015. Note this all happened after I uninstalled VS2017 that I am not using and was only testing out.

`The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets`

I cloned the project fresh, restored nuget packages and made sure node_modules is in order but still get this on two of the projects in the solution.

Any hint or tips would be great. Looks like some sort of Typescript issue and my version when I run `tsc -v` is `2.5.3`

Comment: Attempting a repair now of VS2015, hopefully this will work... will update soon

Comment: Looks like the repair worked. I'll leave this open til tomorrow maybe someone can explain the error a little better. Otherwise will close tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a repair of the Visual Studio 2015 installation worked.

Not sure what caused this exactly, if anyone has more detail please comment and I will add accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on VS2019, and update helped (I presume repair could have helped also but haven't tested that option).

I had uninstalled VS enterprise 2019 some months ago and had forgotten about it, most likely that has caused the issue similar to the OP.